# Postgres count month on the basis of user_id

Tags: postgresql

I want to count number of month for particular user from subscription table. for example user_id = 1 occur 10 times in subscription table like in January it appears 2 time and in February = 0 and again in march = 1 like that

```
user_id   type      started_on  ended_on
 2       P          2009-10-21  2010-03-18  
 2       F          2010-03-18  2010-03-20
 2       P          2010-03-20  2012-05-19
 2       F          2012-05-19  till now
```

Comment: I have no idea from where should I start.  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty basic SQL, I reccomend you read some [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/) before asking it here. About the [Aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) for example. But there you go:

If you want one user:

```
SELECT 
      count(distinct month)
  FROM 
      subscription 
 WHERE 
      user_id=your_user_id_number
```

If you want every user's:

```
SELECT 
      count(distinct month),
      user_id
  FROM 
      subscription 
 GROUP BY 
      user_id
```

Edit:
Ok, so you want the month difference between two date columns, here is how you do it with age():

```
SELECT user_id, extract(YEAR from age(coalesce(ended_on,current_date),started_on)) * 12 + extract(MONTH FROM age(coalesce(ended_on,current_date),started_on)) 
FROM subscription
```

Comment: Yes, Need some more help , There are two fields started_on & ended_on. I want the month count of difference between these two dates. eg started_on = 2009-10-21 and ended_on = 2010-03-18. so the ans is 5.  @perzsa

Comment: Edited the answer, check with this one.

Comment: Edited the question. In that table I want  month count for each row @perzsa